# onmessage Google App Engine (Java) Channel API

Tags: java, google-app-engine, channel-api

Im trying to use the Channel API of Google App Engine.

JavaScript / JQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    alert('ready');

    $.post('/token', function(data) {
        alert('token:' + data['token']);
        openChannel( data['token'] );
    });

    $.post('/chat', function(data) {
        alert('chat:' + data['users'].length);
    });

});


onMessage = function(message) {
    alert(message);
}

onSocketError = function(error){
    alert("Error is <br/>"+error.description+" <br /> and HTML code"+error.code);
};

onSocketOpen = function() {
    // socket opened
};

onSocketClose = function() {
    alert("Socket Connection closed");
};

openChannel = function(token) {
    alert('open channel');
    var channel = new goog.appengine.Channel( token );
    var socket = channel.open();
    socket.onopen = onSocketOpen;
    socket.onmessage = onMessage;
    socket.onerror = onSocketError;
    socket.onclose = onSocketClose;
};
```

The problem is that alert(message) doesn't fire. What is lucking in my code?

Im confused on some of the examples having `"\\{\\{ token \\}\\}"` in server side and `channel = new goog.appengine.Channel('{{ token }}')` in javascript.

What is it enclosed in `{{ }}`?

Comment: In the examples, the '{{ token }}' identifiers in the javascript are meant expanded into values by the template.render function server-side. What's happening in your '/token' handler?

Answer (score 0):

Please note token is a TOKEN KEY which identifies your page. Initialize token in page first like:

```
 ChannelService channelService = ChannelServiceFactory.getChannelService();
 String token = channelService.createChannel("sample");
```

Now

```
var token ="<%=token %>";// This will creaete unique identifier(some id created by google api + ur key)

channel = new goog.appengine.Channel('<%=token%>');    
    socket = channel.open();    

    socket.onopen = function () {
        var connected = true;  
        sendMessage('<b>'+userName+'</b> Logged in.');
    };
```

.. Create  functions like this

Answer (score 0):

Besides using the correct token, your onMessage function doesn't fire because that will happen when you send a message from the server to the client:

```
channelService.sendMessage(new ChannelMessage(channelKey, "Hello World"));
```

you can set up a XMLHttpRequest in order to communicate from the client to the server side, where the java code before can be run, for example:

```
sendMessage = function(path, param) {   
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('GET', 'path + '&' + param', true);
    xhr.send();
};
```

Answer (score 0):

in javascript

```js
 function onMessage(msg) 
           {
  var msg1=msg.data;
  $('textarea').val($('textarea').val()+msg1);

    }
```

in backend

```java
 ChannelService channelService = ChannelServiceFactory.getChannelService();
 channelService.sendMessage(new ChannelMessage(clientid,message));
```